# ruby - adding keys for depth to each nested hash inside larger hash

Tags: ruby, nested, key

I'm trying to write a method that takes a nested hash as input and returns that hash with added "depth" keys. So, for example:

```
hash = { 
  a: 1,
  b: 2, 
  c: { d: { e: 3 } }
}
```

would return:

```
{
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: {
    d: {
      e: 3,
      depth: 2
    },
    depth: 1
  },
  depth: 0
}
```

This is some code I came up with, and it works for this case, or any other hash of up to 2 depth, but I am going about it the wrong way. I'm trying to figure out how to make it work for any depth.

```
def depth(hash)
  hash.values.to_a.map!{|elem| if elem.class==Hash; elem.values.to_a.map!{|el| el.class==Hash ? el[:depth] = 2 : elem}; elem[:depth] = 1; else; elem; end}
  hash[:depth] = 0
  p hash
end
```

You can assume the input is a hash. Thanks :-)

Comment: Why the rush to select an answer? Do you believe it cannot be improved upon? Do you not wish to see other solutions?  You can always change your selection, but wouldn't it be better to simply delay the decision, considering that there's no urgency to making a selection. Most askers wait at least a couple of hours, some much longer, giving then-sleeping members around the world an opportunity to offer solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want a hash returned with the depth value added, you could try something like this:

```
def desc_hash(hash,depth=0)
  ret = {}
  hash.keys.each do |key|
    if hash[key].instance_of?(Hash)
      ret[key] = desc_hash(hash[key],depth+1)
    else
      ret[key] = hash[key]
    end
  end
  ret[:depth]=depth
  ret
end
```

output with your hash as an example:

```
2.7.2 :252 > desc_hash(hash)
 => {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>{:d=>{:e=>3, :depth=>2}, :depth=>1}, :depth=>0}
```

this is a recursive routine that passes the depth through to itself, with any sub-hash.

Comment: `instance_of?` does not detect subclasses

Answer (score 4):

Similar to existing answers, but probably more idiomatic

```
def add_depth(hash, depth = 0)
  hash
    .transform_values { |v| v.is_a?(Hash) ? add_depth(v, depth + 1) : v }
    .merge(depth: depth)
end
```

it essentially does the same as the others, but delegating the creation of the new hash and the iteration to ruby core, which <s>could arguably be more optimal</s> *could possibly be better optimized by the virtual machine*.

Comment: Depending on preference you could further simplify and move the if-statement out of `transform_values` by placing it as a guard clause at the top of the method. `return hash unless hash.is_a?(Hash)`

Comment: nice @3limin4t0r :)

Comment: "More optimal"? Hmmm. Like "more pregnant"?

Comment: like "more better". What I really meant is that by using the proper core method (transform_values), the ruby interpreter might have an opportunity to optimize in a way that could not be done from outside.

Comment: Hey StackOverflow please add the option  to publicly upvote edits. Thank you @3limin4t0r for getting it right.

Answer (score 1):

**In this scenario I would go with the recursive solution**, but managing your own stack has the advantage that you will not hit `SystemStackError (stack level too deep)`

Managing your own stack does make things more complex, but might be worth the effort if your hashes are nested really deep.

```
def depth(hash)
  with_depth = hash.merge({ depth: 0 })
  stack = [with_depth]

  while hash = stack.shift # or .pop
    hash.each_key do |key|
      next unless hash[key].is_a?(Hash)
      hash[key] = hash[key].merge({ depth: hash[:depth] + 1 })
      stack << hash[key]
    end
  end

  with_depth
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one recursive optio, if I got the point.

Given the hash (I added a depth more):

```
hash_ = { 
  a: 1,
  b: 2, 
  c: { d: { e: 3, f: {g: 4} } }
}
```

The method is the following:

```
def depth(hash_, deep=1, root=true)
  hash_[:depth] = 0 if root
  root = false
  hash_.each  do |k, v|
    if v.is_a? Hash
      v[:depth] = deep
      depth(v, deep+=1, root)
    end
  end
end
```

I don't like the `root` switch very much, but this is the first idea I came up with.

So you can call it and check if the result is as expected:

```
depth(hash_)
#=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>{:d=>{:e=>3, :f=>{:g=>4, :depth=>3}, :depth=>2}, :depth=>1}, :depth=>0}
```